# How to open a tab and display text in blank page

Tags: javascript, html, web

When the user click somewhere, I want the browser to open a new tab and display the text I want him to.

I want something exactly like a link with a blank target to a text file on my server, except that the text is generated on the client side by my script, so no interaction with the server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are just looking to display text in a file.  You can build a string with Javascript and then open a new window with that code below.

Please note, that popup blockers do not like window.open.

```
var str = 'hello world';
window.open('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + str);
```

Comment: This no longer works in modern browsers, which appear to have blocked the ability to open data URIs in a new window.